# Katalon Studio SQL Query case statement

Tags: sql-server, katalon-studio

I'm working with Katalon Studio for web testing automation.

I'm using data from database for user login, and I had to difference from *ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_2* that are written with a white space. But when I use this query in Katalon Studio SLQ Query, I get that message below.

I use the same Query in SQL Server Management 2016 and I don't recieve any problems.

```
SELECT  SECU_USERS.USER_LOGIN as login, 
        ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_NAME 
        +' '+ ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_1
        +''+case ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_2 
                when '' then ''
                else ' '+ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_2
            end  
        as name
FROM SECU_USERS 
    inner join ORMA_PROFESSIONALS on  
        SECU_USERS.PROF_ID=ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_ID
```

Error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to identify the table SELECT    SECU_USERS.USER_LOGIN as login, 
        ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_NAME 
        +' '+ ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_1
        +''+case ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_2 
                when '' then ''
                else ' '+ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_2
            end  
        as name
FROM SECU_USERS 
    inner join ORMA_PROFESSIONALS on  
        SECU_USERS.PROF_ID=ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_ID para los metadatos. 
Query: SELECT   SECU_USERS.USER_LOGIN as login, 
        ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_NAME 
        +' '+ ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_1
        +''+case ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_2 
                when '' then ''
                else ' '+ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_SURNAME_2
            end  
        as name
FROM SECU_USERS 
    inner join ORMA_PROFESSIONALS on  
        SECU_USERS.PROF_ID=ORMA_PROFESSIONALS.PROF_ID Parameters: []
```

Comment: The error message implies that Katalon's expecting a table name but getting a SQL query.  Not familiar with Katalon, but hopefully that gives you a starting clue?

Comment: What does the code that executes your query look like (i.e. not just the SQL).  There are some samples here: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/connect_db_gui_testing.html